# Dealing with optional field in json

Tags: java, json

I have am trying to parse a json with following format

```
JSONObject json;
        try {
            json = (JSONObject)parser.parse(value.toString());

            String foo = (String) json.get("foo").toString();//error here
            String id1 = (String) json.get("_id");

            JSONArray array = (JSONArray)json.get("bar");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now, the issue is ...foo and array are optional field.... Sometimes it is present.. othertimes not..

I thought this would work.. except taht I am seeing nullpointer error indicated by comment in above code block..

```
Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hadoop.Foo$MapClass.map(Foo.java:48)
```

Any example json

```
{ "_id" : "foobar", "foo" : null }
{ "_id" : "foobar", "foo" : null , "bar":[{"id":1}]}
{ "_id" : "foobar"}
{ "_id" : "foobar", "foo" : 23 }
```

Comment: What's the JSON look like that you're trying to parse?

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to `toString()` on `null`. For a solution, you can reference Sotirios's answer :)

Comment: Check out the JSONObject class, and all the ´get´ methods it has, it probably has methods which are more suitable for getting values which may be missing... And prefer ´if´ instead of exceptions for handling "normal" stuff such as optional fields which can normally be missing.

Comment: This is a limitation of the API. Is `null` a possible value in your JSON?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: yepp.. maybe i can do an if check before casting it to string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`JSONObject` from `simple json` implements a `Map`](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONObject.html), you can just check that the return value of `get` is not `null` before using it.

However, this is also a limitation of the API. You cannot tell if the `null` originates from the JSON or from the lack of JSON value with `get(String)`.

[As JB Nizet stated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325382/dealing-with-optional-field-in-json/19325434?noredirect=1#comment28626541_19325434), you can use [`containsKey(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) to make that distinction.

Comment: Hi, I am using jsonsimple api.. i dont see any opt method?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: you can use containsKey() to distinguish between absent key and key present but with null value.